# Белый ip адрес через vpn

Tags: linux, ubuntu, openvpn, amazon-web-services

Всем привет! Есть сервер на амазоне (ubuntu) с белым ip, есть ноутбук с серым ip, нужно настроить vpn между ноутбуком и сервером для того что бы получить доступ к ноутбуку из глобальной сети. Нашёл статью на хабре [ссылка](https://habrahabr.ru/post/216101/) попытался на строить по гайду. Файл конфигурации на сервере tun0.conf

```
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.9.8.1 10.9.8.2
secret /etc/openvpn/static.key
route 192.168.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Файл конфигурации на ноутбуке

```
remote 51.54.218.238
dev tun0
ifconfig 10.9.8.2 10.9.8.1
secret C:\static.key
keepalive 60 120
```

При подключении на ноутбуке написано что подключён и присвоен ip 10.9.8.2
но при этом доступ к ноутбуку получить не могу. Подскажите что можно сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас не хватает конфигурации NAT, которая передаст "доступ" с внешнего адреса на адрес тунеля. Смотрите проброс портов.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -dport 80 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.9.8.2:80
```

Не пробрасывайте порт, занятый тунелем - связь оборвётся.

Ещё не уверен что включили форвард `sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`.

Маршрут 192.168.1.0, кажется, не нужен.